# error con instalacion de easyocr en entornovirtual

Tags: python, pip

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](venv_ocr) C:\Users\miky_\OneDrive\Desktop\pruebaocr>pip install easyocr
despues de ejecutar ese comando me sale:
Building wheel for PyWavelets (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [74 lines of output]
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyWavelets
Failed to build PyWavelets
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyWavelets, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

pero luego de ejecutar el comando de pip fuera del entorno virtual instala normal y utilizanco pip freeze aparece todo como si se ubiera instalado normalmente.
porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar esto

Comment: Está pidiendo que instales [VCredist 2015-2022](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022). Si el sistema es 64 bits, instala ambas (x32 y x64).

Comment: gracias aeportugal me soluciono el problema